# How to pass resource from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have three different separate files:

- functions.php (all functions for the database)
- main.html (my main program)
- main.js (all javascript functions)

Now, I want to call a function in PHP through AJAX. To do that, I need to pass $conn.

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

It's a resource, so I can't use json_encode.

The way I set the everything up now is that the php-file is required in the html so I can use the functions and when I change the
value of a dropdown, the js is called.

How can I pass the $conn variable to Javascript?

Regards

Comment: just call $conn in the AJAX script and return data only?

Comment: how can I call $conn if this variable is in a different file than the ajax?

Comment: then include that file?

Comment: or better yet - have a class for db handling and call that class (file include still necessary unless you have namespaces etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work like that.

You should never be directly making calls to the database from the front-end.

Think of it as three separate levels. Your HTML/JS is the front-end, your PHP is your server, and your Database is on its own level.

So when the user does something on the front-end, say changes the value of a field and you want to update that in the database the following actions should happen:

- Event triggers on JS
- AJAX is called as a result of the event being triggered
- PHP server receives the AJAX request and executes code to modify database
- (optional) PHP server sends something back to the front-end to tell it that the request was successful

Read up on the concept of MVC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Modern_web_app_architecture/MVC_architecture

Answer (score 0):

Try this in php code as I assume `functions.php`

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
echo $conn;//Don't try echo anything other
```

In Javascript

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "functions.php",

           success: function(data)
           {
               var conn = data; // here is your conn which comes from php file
           }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all include jquery latest version from cdn

1. Create an API Url, and use *POST* method

   ```
   site.com/api/insert.php // to insert into table
   ```
2. Use $.post() api of jquery to send data

   ```
   var url = ""; // enter your URL HERE
   var postData = {};  // object of post data with table name, cols and values
   $.post(url, postData, function(data, status) {
          // do what ever you want with data        
   })
   ```

   ps: you can also create diff insertion / selection / update / delete api for different table. (recommended)

Read more about $.post() [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)